# How can I effectively debug Anylogic project?

Tags: java, debugging, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am a newbie in Anylogic Simulation Software Tool and trying to do an agent-based simulation.

I read the variables from an excel sheet and planning to use them for my agents. In the excel sheet, there are columns such as agent strategy(per agent), speed, map environment things, and so on. What I try to do is each agent created with these data specifically.

Question 1: Is there any example project similar to my project explained above?

I can read the data from excel and use some of them in my simulation. But at some point, I faced problems that I can not solve or debug.

When I double-clicked or searched the problem in my project; there was nothing opened.

Question 2: How can I effectively debug a problem in Anylogic? Can I debug it from its generated Java code as if a java project? Is there a better approach except for adding debug logs everywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ösgür, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask only 1 question per post. To read more about asking better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I have answered your second question as your first is just about an example model - which you can find here L https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnyLogic has a standard debug feature like most Java IDEs.

To add a debug point simply double click inside the grey area on the left of any place where you can write code

[image]

and then you can run the model in debug mode using the debug run mode icon (right next to the play icon)

[image]

You can read more about it here - https://anylogic.help/advanced/debug/launching-in-debug-mode.html